# Pytorch : GPU Memory Leak

Tags: deep-learning, parallel-processing, pytorch, conv-neural-network, gpu

I speculated that I was facing a GPU memory leak in the training of Conv nets using PyTorch framework. Below image

[image]

To resolve it, I added -

`os.environ['CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING'] = "1"`

which resolved the memory problem, as shown below -
[image]

but as I was using `torch.nn.DataParallel`, so I expect my code to utilise all the GPUs, but now it is utilising only the `GPU:1`.

[image]

Before using `os.environ['CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING'] = "1"`, the GPU utilisation was below (which is equally bad)-

[image]

On digging [further](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/9163), I come to know that, when we use `torch.nn.DataParallel`, we are supposed to not use `CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING'`, because it puts the network in some deadlock mechanism.
So, now I have come back again in GPU memory issue, because I think my code is not utilising that much memory which it is showing without setting `CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1`.
My code to use `torch.nn.DataParallel`-

```
device =  torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
  print("Let's use", torch.cuda.device_count(), "GPUs!")
  # dim = 0 [30, xxx] -> [10, ...], [10, ...], [10, ...] on 3 GPUs
  model_transfer = nn.DataParallel(model_transfer.cuda(),device_ids=range(torch.cuda.device_count()))


model_transfer.to(device)
```

How to resolve the GPU memory issue?
Edit:
Minimal code -

```
image_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(train_dir_path,transform = transform)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(image_dataset['train'], batch_size=batch_size,shuffle = True)
model_transfer = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)

device =  torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
  print("Let's use", torch.cuda.device_count(), "GPUs!")
  # dim = 0 [30, xxx] -> [10, ...], [10, ...], [10, ...] on 3 GPUs
  model_transfer = nn.DataParallel(model_transfer.cuda(),device_ids=range(torch.cuda.device_count()))
model_transfer.to(device) 

## Training function
for epoch in range(1, n_epochs+1):
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
                    if use_cuda:
            data, target = data.to('cuda',non_blocking = True), target.to('cuda',non_blocking = True)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data)
        loss = criterion(output,target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        train_loss += ((1 / (batch_idx + 1)) * (loss.item() - train_loss))

   ## Validation loop same as training loop so not mentioning here

    print('Epoch: {} \tTraining Loss: {:.6f} \tValidation Loss: {:.6f}'.format(
        epoch,
        train_loss,
        valid_loss
        ))
        if valid_loss <= valid_loss_min:
           valid_loss_min,valid_loss))
           torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'case_3_model.pt')
           valid_loss_min = valid_loss
```

Answer (score 5):

So the way I resolved some of my CUDA out of memory issue is by making sure to delete useless tensors and trim tensors that may stay referenced for some hidden reason. The problem may arise from either requesting for more memory than you have the capacity for or an accumulation of garbage data that you don't need, but somehow is left behind on the memory.

One of the most important aspects of this memory management is how you are loading in the data. Instead of reading the entire dataset, it may be more memory efficient to read from disk (using memmap when reading npy) or doing batch loading, where you only read a batch of images or whatever data you have at a time. Although this may be computationally slower, it does give you flexibility for not going out and buying more GPUS to store your memory just to run your code.

We're not sure how your code is structured in terms of reading the data or training your CNN so this is as much advice I can give.

Comment: Thank You, I'll try to change it according to suggestions, I have also added the code in case you want to have a look at it.

Comment: So one of the critical things I've changed is the use of loss.item. this gives you the loss but also somehow keeps your tensor around (this may or may not be true, but my memory doesn't run out afterward). Instead, try deleting loss after each iteration, and use loss.float() instead.

Comment: Ultimately, I haven't played around with data parallelism because I only have one gpu and I'm still in the process of learning PyTorch (I started with Keras). So from my perspective, the code you are showing right now seems fine. There may be some straggling tensors elsewhere.

Comment: Here's a great example of what I'm talking about from the pytorch faq https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/faq.html